# php - Can print multidimensional array, but not echo single value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

After posting an array, I am able to print_r to display the entire array, but I cannot echo a single value.  I need to get those single values so that I can put them in the value tag of a text item.  Currently, every time I post the page, those values disappear, and it's because I cannot find how to grab the corresponding value.

When I print_r($subs) I get the correct values -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['subs_name'] => Image PC and load programs
            ['subs_target'] => 03/10/2015
            ['subs_owner'] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['subs_name'] => Update Inventory
            ['subs_target'] => 03/17/2015
            ['subs_owner'] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['subs_name'] => Deploy PC
            ['subs_target'] => 03/24/2015
            ['subs_owner'] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['subs_name'] => Follow up with user
            ['subs_target'] => 03/31/2015
            ['subs_owner'] => 1
        )

)
```

If I attempt to echo $subs[0]['subs_target'] I don't get any return.  I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, but I can't pinpoint what that is.  I've scanned around a few articles and have not found the solution.

Here is the form input I am using to set the array -

```
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "                  <tr>\n";
        echo "                      <td>\n";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"subs[$count]['subs_name']\" class=\"none\" value=\"" . $row['prosub_name'] . "\">";
        echo "<p>" . $row['prosub_name'] . "</p>";
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "                      <td align=\"center\">\n";
        echo "                          <input type=\"text\" class=\"datepicker\" name=\"subs[$count]['subs_target']\" value=\"" . $subs["$count"]['subs_target'] . "\">\n"; 
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "                      <td align=\"center\">\n";
        echo "                          <select name=\"subs[$count]['subs_owner']\" class=\"diedit\">\n"; 
        getUserDD($hid_owner, 'acc_tix_pro');
        echo "                          </select>\n"; 
        echo "                      </td>\n";
        echo "                  </tr>\n";
        $count++;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No error, just no value either.  If I write echo "~" . $subs[0]['subs_target'] . "~"; I get a return of ~~

Comment: try error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: is that really the `print_r` dump? (meaning untouched), the indices aren't supposed to be quoted, unless there's a literal single quote, which is odd. try `echo $subs[0]["'subs_target'"]` if thats the case

Comment: Ghost, that was it.  I was putting single quotes around the name of the input.

Comment: @1484 then just take off the single quotes in the name value, hassle having them there, so that you'll be able to just wrap the array index with a simple single quote

Comment: Do you want to put that in an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

try to check the value not with echo, but with var_dump:

```
 var_dump($subs[0]['subs_target']);
```

Comment: I get a value of NULL.  This is directly in front of the print_r.  I've added the input portion of my code to the original question, as it may be some weird thing that I did while building the array.

Comment: $subs["$count"] might be different from $subst[$count], the latter makes more sense to me